# Select tag with ng-model dose not show the default value set in the controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In pagination i have provided the drop down option to select the number of items shown on each page. But the select is not showing the default values set in the controller.

Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/bqLKGB2nBK6m53XJ1U85?p=preview

```
  <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="pageSize">
<option value="10" selected>10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `ng-value`:

```
<select name="singleSelect" ng-model="pageSize">
      <option ng-value="10">10</option>
      <option ng-value="20">20</option>
      <option ng-value="30">30</option>
      <option ng-value="50">50</option>
      <option ng-value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

Or modify this row without applying `ng-value`:

```
$scope.pageSize = '10';
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple way to work with [`select` in `angularjs 1.*`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .run(function TestCtrl($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.sizes = [
      10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
    ];
    
    $rootScope.size = $rootScope.sizes[0];
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="test">
  <h1> Size is: <code ng-bind="size"></code></h1>


  <select
    ng-model="size"
    ng-options="s for s in sizes">
  </select>

</section>
```